# Custom User Role not working

Tags: functions, multisite, user-roles

I've created a custom user role that I want to only be able to access a CPT Job Listings

Below is my code for the custom user role ( this is on a multisite network ) which I have added to my themes functions.php

```
function custom_add_job_listings_editor_role() {
    // Get all the sites in the network
    $sites = get_sites();

    foreach ($sites as $site) {
        switch_to_blog($site->blog_id);

        // Define capabilities for the role
        $capabilities = array(
            'read' => true,
            'edit_job_listings' => true,
            'delete_job_listings' => true,
            'publish_job_listings' => true,
            'edit_published_job_listings' => true,
        );

        // Add the custom role
        add_role('job_listings_editor', 'Job Listings Editor', $capabilities);

        restore_current_blog();
    }
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_add_job_listings_editor_role');
```

After running the code I can create a user of type "Job Listings Editor"

But when logging into the site with the newly created user, there is nothing listed. The CPT is not available.

When I try to manually access the CPT page via mysite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=job_listings

I get the classic "you are not allowed to access this page" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The capabilities should match in 2 functions: When you register CPT, when you register user role. 
Can you post the code for CPT registration.